# Проиграть анимацию UserControl до установки Visibility.Collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, animate

Проблема следующая, сделал свой UserControl. В коде этого контрола привязался к событию IsVisibleChanged и проигрываю анимацию появления\закрытия.

```
private void sVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            _OnShowStoryboard.Begin();
        }
        else
        {

            _OnCollapseStoryboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

Анимация появления работает нормально, но анимации закрытия нету. Как я понял, свойство Visibility устанавливается до вызова этого события и анимация играется уже на спрятанном контроле. Как это изменить?

Comment: Делайте наоборот — не анимацию запускайте по изменению свойства, а сначала запускайте анимацию и вешайте триггер на конечное состояние. По триггеру скрывайте контрол

Comment: @АндрейNOP я сделал депенденси проперти IsOpen и повесил на него changecallback в котором в зависимости от значения (true\false) в определённом порядке запускаю анимацию и задаю значение Visibility. Так же тоже можно или лучше не делать так и переписать на тригерах?

Comment: Можно и так, почему нет?